# Id selector for queryString based on the similar indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an query to select all ID's which ends with "-1". For this the below code is working fine

```
  var queryString = ':input:focusable[id$="-' + index + '"]'; 
  element.find(queryString);
```

I have a condition like the following ID's ends with like below..

```
 -index
 -index-0
 -index-1
 ... so on
```

So how to handle this in a single query.as i mentioned above.  Could any of the folks help on this??

Comment: Could you give examples of actual IDs?  It's unclear if `index` is a literal or a number in your current example.

Comment: Hi Rick, the id's will be in the following format 
-0
-0-1
-0-2
..
..
ends with...

Comment: I will get ID's like ends with -0, -0-1, -0-2 and -1, -1-0, -1-1 and so on...

Comment: That's a selector, not a query string. A query string is something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't support RegExp in selectors, which would be necessary to catch all possibilities of an ending number.

Instead, you could use **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

```
$('input:focusable').filter(function() {
  var re= new RegExp('-' + index + '(-\\d+)?$'); //ends with -index, which may or may not
                                                 //be followed by -number
  return re.test(this.id);
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
var index= 1,
    inputs= $('input').filter(function() {
      var re= new RegExp('-' + index + '(-\\d+)?$');
      return re.test(this.id);
    });

inputs.addClass('found');
```

```css
.found {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="abc-1" type="text">
<input id="def-1-0" type="text">
<input id="ghi-1-1" type="text">
<input id="jkl-1mno-0" type="text">
<input id="-1pqr-0" type="text">
<input id="stu-1-159" type="text">
```